# adding variable into an array in a function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a problem with putting a variable into my array. Here is my code:

```
var info = new Array();
google.load("feeds", "1");

function initialize() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/24927681/device/rss/rss.xml");
  feed.setNumEntries(6);

  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      var html = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var a = " " ;
        a += entry.title;
        info[i] = a

       html += '<p>' + entry.publishedDate + '&nbsp' + entry.title;
      }
      container.innerHTML = html;
    }
    alert(info[0]);
  });
  //alert(info[0]);
}
//alert(info[0]);
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

You see an array called info. I'm trying to add entry.title into it. You can see some places are commented out. There my info[0] is empty. I can display my result only in function(result), except that it doesn't display anything like I never put anything inside my array. I didn't understand why.

Updated:

```
    var info = new Array();
google.load("feeds", "1");
function initialize(cb) {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/24927681/device/rss/rss.xml");
  feed.setNumEntries(6);

  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      var html = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i]; 
       html += '<p>' + entry.publishedDate + '&nbsp' + entry.title;
        cb(entry.title);

      }
      container.innerHTML = html;
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
initizalize(processInfo);}
);
function processInfo(information){
    info[info.length] = information;
    alert(info[info.length]);
}
```

Last Version

```
    var info = new Array();
google.load("feeds", "1");
function initialize(cb) {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/24927681/device/rss/rss.xml");
  feed.setNumEntries(6);

  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      var html = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var a= " ";
        a += entry.title;
        info[i] = a;
       html += '<p>' + entry.publishedDate + '&nbsp' + entry.title;
      }
      container.innerHTML = html;
    }
     cb(info);
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
initizalize(processInfo);}
);
function processInfo(info){
    alert(info[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't display `info` in those points because the call to `feed.load()` is *asynchronous*, and hasn't finished by that point.

You need to make *all* processing continue in the `.load` callback function, e.g. something like:

```
function initialize(cb) {
  feed.load(function(result) {
    ...
    cb(info);   // only call the callback once the data is loaded
  });
}

// call the above function, passing a callback handler
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  initialize(processInfo);
}));

// defer all of your data processing to here
function processInfo(info) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: how can I make it? Is it possible? I'm using Google API for RSS to Javascript

Comment: you just have to structure your code so that your `initialise()` call doesn't fall through to the next phase, but instead calls it at the end of the callback.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't follow what you said =) What does calling at the end of the callback mean?

Comment: Ohh I think I understood, but what is cb? I think it refers to processInfo but, can I write cb directly?

Comment: If you can write extacly, I would be really happy.

Comment: @AhmetTanakol the point is that `cb` can do _anything_ - but in this instance I'm passing it a reference to `processInfo`.

Comment: You can see the updated version of this piece of code. NoW in this format,it doesn't display any of my RSS feeds. Where is my mistake. processInfo is empty. What should I write there.

Comment: you've put the call to `cb` too early - it should be the very last line of the `if` condition in the `.load()` anonymous function.  Your `processInfo` needs to contain whatever code it was you planned to use the `info` array for.

Comment: So for instance, I need to put entry.title into array. I put entry.title as paramater into processInfo and after I insert it into array. By the way, you said last line of if condition.I can't take cb out of for loop. Otherwise I can't get title for each entry.

Comment: @AhmetTanakol yes, I saw it - you completely changed your code.  Originally you were collecting the titles in an array.  I was proposing you pass that whole array to the `cb` _outside_ the loop.

Comment: By the way thank you for spending yout time=) I updated code again. Still can't see RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

That's because AJAX is Asynchronous, basically meaning it won't run until at least the rest of the code has been run. Anything that relies on stuff that's defined an an AJAX call (or any other asynchronous callback) MUST be inside that callback, or itself deferred until later.

Comment: Hmm, then how I can do that. I mean how I can use use this array with its values after this function

Comment: Depends on how you want to use it, exactly. For instance, you could define an anonymous function after the AJAX call, but call it at the end of the AJAX success callback.

Comment: I don't have much information what you said. I want to store for example entry.title in this array. How can I write that function?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `result.feed.entries.length` is non-zero and that you are actually executing the `for` loop. Also (but minor) it wouldn't hurt to have a `;` after the `info[i] = a`